# How can I output a dict with "resolved" foreign_keys? Human *string* readable models. EXTENDING the main model with a smart one

Tags: python, django, dictionary, unicode, foreign-keys

I need to output many models in some human readable way.
I'll like to:

- replace objects linked with foreign_keys ids with their unicode representation
- replace objects linked with many2many relationships with their unicode representation, comma separated, in one unicode

all of that, outputting in a dict (eg.)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year_of_birth = models.IntegerField()
    father = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(Person)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I'll like to do:

```
class **SMART_MODEL**(models.Model):
    pass

    def human_unicode(self):
        pass
        # ...
        return dict

class Person(models.Model, **SMART_MODEL**):
    # ...



Person.objects.first().human_unicode()
output:
{"name": "John","year_of_birth": 1979, "father":"Barry", "mother":"Gina", "friends":"Paul,Brandon"}


Person.objects.all()[:2].human_unicode()
output:
[{"name": "John","year_of_birth": 1979, "father":"Barry", "mother":"Gina","friends":"Paul,Brandon"},
{"name":"Egon","year_of_birth": 1969,"father":"Carl", "mother":"Fiona", "friends":"Peter, Raymond, Winston"}]
```

As you see I'll like to do it at "instance level" and at "queryset level"

That way I could extend many models as I'll like.

Nobody need that?

Any idea on where to start?
Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't understand why you're going to need it but anyway.
Here is what I'd recommend.
You can use "django-rest-framework". 
[django-rest-framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

In tutorial, there is a section called "serialization". By using it, you can create serializers for your models. Also rest-framework supports ListAPIView which you can show the serialized queries very easily.
I don't know your level of knowledge. If you stuck with something, I can provide you an example.

Comment: Thank you Barin. I explain you in few words what I'm doing. I have a db with  100~ tables. Some of data are georeferenced. I'm making a custom query builder that could output: querysets, geoquerysets, lists of objects, objects, numbers, booleans and strings. The querybuilder output will be: a page with a table (or something else in case the output is number, string, bool...) and in case of geodata, a map. The querybuilder should also let the user exports a CSV. I already done 90% of work. What I dislike (and client too) are the foreignkeys while looking at their datas. Wrong approach?